# Issue while calling MS graph API

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I am working on an API that will download the videos from OneDrive by providing a URI.

I was able to get the access token but when I try to download the file I get an error stating:

> /me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.

Below is the code that I used.

I got the access token using this API-

```
client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
token_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token'

# Fetch the access token
token = oauth.fetch_token(
    token_url=token_url,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    scope=scope
)

# Print the access token
print(token['access_token'])`
This worked fine.

then I called this api to fetch file details-
`file_url = 'onedrive file url'

# Set the API endpoint and parameters
url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Documents/{file_url}:/'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
}

# Make the API request to get the file metadata
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Get the file ID and name from the metadata
    file_id = response.json()['id']
    file_name = response.json()['name']
    print(f'File ID: {file_id}, File Name: {file_name}')

    # Download the file content
    download_url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{file_id}/content'
    response = requests.get(download_url, headers=headers)

    # Check if the download was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Write the file to disk
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
        print(f'{file_name} has been downloaded.')
    else:
        print(f'Error downloading {file_name}: {response.text}')
else:
    print(f'Error getting metadata for {file_url}: {response.text}')`
```

This returns the error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-03-27T21:15:20",
            "request-id": "d2f3f66b-7bc8-4806-a082-f2d763482570",
            "client-request-id": "d2f3f66b-7bc8-4806-a082-f2d763482570"
        }
    }
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the `/me` path segment using an app-only token (i.e. the Client_Credentials OAuth flow).

The `/me` segment is an alias for `/users/{current user id}`. When you authenticate using Client Credentials, you are authenticating as an Application rather than on-behalf of a given User. Without a User, there is no way for Graph to determine which User in AAD `/me` should map to.

You will either need to explicitly reference the User (`/users/{id}`) or switch to using an Authorization Code flow. This OAuth flow will generate a token on behalf of the authenticated User and enable the `/me` segment.